# Multiple isotope containers, Imageloaded only loading one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope, imagesloaded

The title is pretty much explaining my issue I guess, I'm using Bootstrap tabs so my html looks like this:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="isotopegrid tab-pane fade in">
        // Images here
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="isotopegrid tab-pane fade in">
        // And images here
    </div>
</div>
```

The images look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 isotopegrid-item">
    <img src="#" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

This is my Js:

```
(function ($) {
    var $container = $('.isotopegrid');
    $container.each( function( i, elem ){
        var $elem = $( elem );

        $elem.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $elem.isotope({
                itemSelector : '.isotopegrid-item',
                layoutMode: 'masonry'
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But for some reason, it only loads tab1 and not tab2, anyone here got a solution for me? Oh and with not loading i mean that the images on tab1 are loaded properly, and the images on tab 2 are overlapping

Answer (score 0):

Since your using a class for your $container, not an ID, you can just do this:

```
var $container = $('.isotopegrid');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.isotopegrid-item',
            layoutMode: 'masonry'
        });
    });
```

Without a jsfiddle to actually see the issue, it is impossible to know what other issues might be the source of your problem.

Comment: Made an jsfiddle but it isnt showing anything, here is my [link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10080/)

Comment: updated my jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10085/) still showing nothing tho

Comment: im giving up, jsfiddle does not want to show anything, while im using the exact code im using on my website, and its working there, and besides that, nobody tried to help me except you, and its been on here for 2 hours already.

Comment: 2hours? Relax man, sometimes it takes days for an answer. Don't be so impatient. Do you  think we are on here 24 hours a day waiting to answer your question.

Comment: You need to load jquery 2.1.0 and check the loading of Bootstrap. Then remove loading bootstrap in your external resources. You are loading an alpha version of jQuery 3! Plus your html is incomplete to show your tabs,they do  not contain anything, i.e. your images.